# Detect Audible Sound with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, system

Is there any way to detect whether a certain page is making noise using jscript? Some sort of environmental variable or something that tracks the status of the speakers? I'm attempting to write a script that puts an icon on the Tab Title if that Tab is making sound.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437228/html5-check-if-audio-is-playing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

Lots of plugins can make sound, and they all do it in their own way.  There is no catch-all here.

Perhaps on Vista/7 where applications sound usage is actually kept track of, and when using a browser like Chrome that makes a separate process for each page, you might have more luck.  It would involve figuring out which processes are playing sound, then figuring out what page each process had loaded.  Through JavaScript though?  No way.

Comment: Is it possible to make user scripts for chrome in something other than javascript? I'm assuming a C type language would be best suited for this. Maybe it just has to be a plugin that isn't necessarily a script?

Comment: I think you have to think outside Chrome and program something OS-related, that can analyze processes, especially Chrome's processses and determine wheter they're making sound or not by using the Vista/7 feature mentionned above... Good luck though !

Answer (score 1):

Scraped from [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Why-dont-browsers-build-an-indication-of-which-tab-is-playing-sound)

> The majority of sound on the web is
>   done through Flash. Flash doesn't
>   inform the browser when it is making
>   sound. That is to say, if two
>   different tabs are running Flash, the
>   browser can't know which is the one
>   making sound.
>
> The introduction of the HTML5 media
>   tags could help in this area, but I
>   suspect an audio indicator that only
>   worked some of the time (for non-Flash
>   pages) would be more frustrating than
>   no audio indicator.

(Pay no attention to the comment below (in the linked Quora question) saying Chrome displays a 'play' icon when sound is played. That's Soundcloud changing the title of its own page, not Google Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can detect whether or not the speakers are making noise in JavaScript, however you may not have to.

Perhaps you could keep track of this yourself, implicitly.  So for example, if there is a play button, on click you could start playing the audio and show the icon.  Once the user clicks the stop button, you stop the audio and hide the icon.

Comment: I'm not trying to do this for a single page. It's going to be a user-script that is run when every page is loaded, so whenever any page is making noise, the icon is displayed.

Comment: It looks like the goal is to write a browser plugin. Not sure how useful this answer is.

Comment: Yes I am writing a browser plugin. My question is if there is a method to, via javascript in a browser plugin, detect if the page in question is using the speakers on my computer to make noise.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you, `fbc_array` is de array noise use `fbc_array[value]` for get this noise.
example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var file = document.querySelector('input');
  file.onchange = function(e) {
    var boton = e.target.files;
    var archivo = boton[0];
    if (!archivo.type.match(/audio/)) {
      alert("Seleciona un audio, por favor.");
    } else {
      var lector = new FileReader();
      lector.readAsDataURL(archivo);
      lector.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);
    }
  }

  function initMp3Player(e) {
    var result = e.target.result;
    var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
    audio.src = result;
    context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    frameLooper();
  }

  function frameLooper() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
    document.querySelector('#o1').style.transform = 'scale(' + fbc_array[1] / 75 + ')';
    document.querySelector('#o2').style.transform = 'scale(' + fbc_array[50] / 100 + ')';
    document.querySelector('#o3').style.transform = 'scale(' + fbc_array[100] / 200 + ')';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
body {
  background: #222;
}
input {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgb(76, 142, 250);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .875em;
  padding: 10px 24px;
}
#o1 {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #333;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#o2 {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #0074d9;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#o3 {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="file"></input>
<audio autoplay></audio>
<div id="o1"></div>
<div id="o2"></div>
<div id="o3"></div>
```