# Detecting audio in third party online advertisements

Tags: javascript, .net, flash, audio

Is is possible to detect when an online advertisement is playing audio?  In an ideal world, I could do this through a browser in real-time and send a notification that would include the DOM information needed to remove the ad.  In this type of model, I could theoretically then use all clients (web visitors) as test subjects.  I believe that this might be far fetched, and thus will need to rely on a smaller subset of users.   I'm looking for any way to do this.  I have even thought about using speakers and a microphone to detect when a sound is playing, and then some how capture a screenshot and the DOM information.  Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995548/detect-sound-javascript), it was stated that this is not possible.

---

Edit:

No. The best you could do is *maybe* be able to detect that the browser *is* or *is not* playing sound. Even if you could do that, you would have difficulty detecting *which* tab or page was creating the sound. And if you *could*, you would have difficulty detecting the offending HTML. Could be flash, javascript, or HTML 5's  tag. And even if you could do *all of this*, IE would surely (being the pain that it is) not support any of your attempts to complete this objective.

**Bottom Line:** You simply can't do what you are wanting to do. You would need to be able to query the browser for playing audio to be confident that you could handle all supported methods of playing sound in a browser. AFAIK, no browsers support this, so you are out of luck.

Comment: Is it possible outside the browser environment?