# HTML5 check if audio is playing?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

What's the javascript api for checking if an html5 audio element is currently playing?

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877403/how-to-tell-if-a-video-element-is-currently-playing

Answer (score 228, accepted):

```
function isPlaying(audelem) { return !audelem.paused; }
```

The Audio tag has a [`paused`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/paused) property. If it is not paused, then it's playing.

Comment: Since there is no stop this is a clean solution.

Comment: Then `paused` is true and so `isPlaying()` returns false.

Comment: This is wrong answer. I am just working with it, and before the first start .paused is false.

Comment: @Tom you have a jsbin? I tried this and it seems like the correct answer.

Comment: @Harry I was playing around with it more and it seems like in some browsers it does work and it some not. I guess it depends on implementation. But for all latest updates for chrome and firefox it seems to work, so This answer is correct for latest implementations.

Comment: You can also use the `ended` listener so that you do not restart the audio when it finishes playing.

Comment: listen for events! addEventListener('playing', func) and addEventListener('pause', func).

Comment: According to both the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-paused) and the [W3C HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/embedded-content-0.html#htmlmediaelement), "The `paused` attribute represents whether the media element is paused or not. The attribute must initially be true". Maybe @Harry and @Tomas found this not to be the case in 2012 because the specs were not clear at that point. BUT ... I couldn't find anything in the specs (not to say it's not there!) that says that the 'paused`  attribute must be true when playback ends. Any views?

Answer (score 62):

You can check the duration. It is playing if the duration is more than 0 seconds and it is not paused.

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudioID');

if (myAudio.duration > 0 && !myAudio.paused) {

    //Its playing...do your job

} else {

    //Not playing...maybe paused, stopped or never played.

}
```

Comment: Personally I believe that `!myAudio.paused||!myAudio.currentTime` would do a better job.

Comment: @m93a don't you mean `!myAudio.paused || myAudio.currentTime` ?

Comment: Yes, should be `!myAudio.paused || myAudio.currentTime`. Never replied back it seems...

Comment: @MalcolmOcean ty from 2023 <3

Answer (score 26):

While I am really late to this thread, I use this implementation to figure out if the sound is playing:

```
service.currentAudio = new Audio();

var isPlaying = function () {
    return service.currentAudio
        && service.currentAudio.currentTime > 0
        && !service.currentAudio.paused
        && !service.currentAudio.ended
        && service.currentAudio.readyState > 2;
}
```

I think most of the flags on the audio element are obvious apart from the ready state which you can read about here: [MDN HTMLMediaElement.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState).

Comment: Doesn't work if audio was paused automatically by iOS when locked.

Answer (score 14):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('audio').addEventListener('playing',function() { myfunction(); },false);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]` because it returns collection, not one element

Answer (score 9):

Try this function!
Audio playing would not be executed if the position is the beginning or ending

```
function togglePause() {
     if (myAudio.paused && myAudio.currentTime > 0 && !myAudio.ended) {
         myAudio.play();
     } else {
         myAudio.pause();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wondered if this code would work, and it amazingly did:

```
if (a.paused == false) {
/*do something*/
}
```

or you could write it as:

```
if (!a.paused == true) {
/*do something*/
}
```

if you want your IDE annoying you in JSfiddle.

Comment: Maybe you could also replace "paused" with "running" and it would still work

Comment: Or you can just omit the "== true" part, and your IDE won't bug you.

Answer (score 2):

you can to use the onplay event.

```
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.onplay = function() { /* do something */};
```

or

```
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.addEventListener('play', function() { /* do something */ };
```

Comment: The second method seems to work best. Firefox, Linux Mint, in footer script.

Answer (score 2):

Try Out This Code:

```js
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("audioFile"); 

    function playAudio() { 
          //audio.play(); 
          //console.log(audio.play())
           if (myAudio.paused && myAudio.currentTime >= 0 && !myAudio.started) {
         myAudio.play();
         console.log("started");
     } else {
         myAudio.pause();
     }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

To check if audio is really start playing, especially if you have a stream, need to check `audio.played.length` to `1`. It will be 1 only if audio is really start sounds. Otherwise will be `0`. It's more like a hack, but that still works even in mobile browsers, like Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I do this way

```
    <button id="play">Play Sound</button>
<script>
    var sound = new Audio("path_to_sound.mp3")
    sound.loop = false;
    var play = document.getElementById("play")
    play.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (!isPlaying()) {
            sound.play()
        } else {
            //sound.pause()  
        }
    })

    function isPlaying() {
        var infoPlaying = false
        var currentTime = sound.currentTime == 0 ? true : false
        var paused = sound.paused ? true : false
        var ended = !sound.ended ? true : false
        var readyState = sound.readyState == 0 ? true : false
        if (currentTime && paused && ended && readyState) {
            infoPlaying = true
        } else if (!currentTime && !paused && ended && !readyState) {
            infoPlaying = true
        }
      return infoPlaying
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer by @AllanRibas, in which the function should rather look like this in my opinion:

```js
let plr = document.querySelector("#player-audio-element");
if(isPlaying(plr) === true) {
    // do stuff ...
}

export function isPlaying(plr) {
    let atStart = plr.currentTime == 0 ? true : false
    if ((atStart && plr.paused) || (plr.ended && plr.readyState == 0))
        return false
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for play pause audio button

```
    var audio=$("audio").get[0];
    if (audio.paused || audio.currentTime == 0 || audio.currentTime==audio.duration){
//audio paused,ended or not started
            audio.play();
        } else {
//audio is playing
            audio.pause();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

am using this jquery code  withe tow button play and stop, play button is a play and pouse button

```
const help_p = new Audio("audio/help.mp3");//Set Help Audio Name
$('#help_play').click(function() {//pause-Play
if (help_p.paused == false) {
  help_p.pause();//pause if playing
} else {
  help_p.play();//Play If Pausing
}
});

$('#help_stop').click(function() {//Stop Button
  help_p.pause();//pause
  help_p.currentTime = 0; //Set Time 0
});
```

Answer (score -3):

While there is no method called isPlaying or something similar, there are a few ways to accomplish this.

This method gets the % of progress as audio is playing:

```
function getPercentProg() {
    var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    var endBuf = myVideo.buffered.end(0);
    var soFar = parseInt((endBuf / myVideo.duration) * 100);
    document.getElementById('loadStatus').innerHTML =  soFar + '%';
}
```

If percent is greater than 0 and less than 100, it is playing, else it is stopped.

Comment: Erm, what if I pause the audio in the middle?

Comment: Then it would not be playing.

Comment: This only detects the amount buffered. If, for instance, the audio element has begun buffering data but has not started playing because it doesn't have enough data, this method can still return true. Or if the element has buffered data as part of playback and subsequently was paused.

Comment: getElementsByTagName('myVideo') ? i think it should be getElementById('myVideo')

Comment: Em... Why minusing? A great idea, bad written though. How can you check if realtime audio (WebRTC) is playing with .paused? Only with buffer checking. Not deserved minusing. I upvote.

Comment: Wtf?! Why double-parenthesized parseInt?