# How to uncheck a checkbox if audio stops?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, windows-8, checkbox

I have a checkbox that plays audio when it's checked and stops playing audio when unchecked. But the audio stops at a point if you keep it checked because of the length of the audio. When the audio ends I want to set the checkbox to unchecked. How do I check if the audio has stopped in javascript.

Sorry if I used the word check too many times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437228/html5-check-if-audio-is-playing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a event like this:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("#audio");

audio.addEventListener("ended", function() { 

   var checkbox = document.getElementById("#checkbox1");
   checkbox.checked = false;

}, true);
```

Also you can check if the browser supports **onended** event using:

`audio.hasOwnProperty('ended')`