# How to disable the click if a function is in active status

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, disabled-control

I have created  a fiddle of my function here( http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/10/ ) . Now i want to disable the button click i.e `play/pause` if the sound is playing like `Get ready,5,4,3,2,1` .

I know only how to disable the form submit button , but I am very confused how to disable the click in my case the `hyperlinks`.

**Explanation using code example:**

I want to disable this

```
<a href="#" id="btn_start">PLAY</a>
```

click, while interpreter is executing the below code:

```
var playGetReady = function (done) {
    var ids = ['audiosource', 'a_5', 'a_4', 'a_3', 'a_2', 'a_1'],
        playNext = function () {
            var id = ids.shift();
            document.getElementById(id).play();
            if (ids.length) {
                setTimeout(playNext, 1000);
            } else {
                done();
            }
        };
    playNext();
};
```

**Warning: *This JS fiddle demo may play sound on load***

Comment: Why i a not receiving any answer for this above question. Does my question is not proper or some other mistake from my side?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. StackOverflow is a place where mostly humans dwell. While there are some wizards that can write up the most amazing answers in 6 minutes time, most humans require a little more than that. Please... be patient...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437228/html5-check-if-audio-is-playing

Comment: an easy solution... set a flag e.g. `window.__compilerbusy = true` when running the timer, set it to false when timer is done. In btn click handler, check for the flag.

Comment: `while complier is executing` no it's `interpreter` in case of `JavaScript`.

Comment: @gp. Thank you, but i found `Recovering Since 2003` answer very easy and fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (Changes in following function), but not sure if this is you want and maybe there are other ways to do it.

```
App.prototype.start = function () {
    var self = this;
    // unbind for a while
    self.$button.unbind('click', self.buttonHandler); // <--
    var start = function () {
            // start countdown
            self.intervalHandle = setInterval($.proxy(self.tick, self), 1000);
            // bind again
            self.$button.click($.proxy(self.buttonHandler, self)); // <--
            // change button text to PAUSE
            self.$button.text('PAUSE');
        };

    if (this.newTimer) {
        playGetReady(start);
    } else {
        start();
    }
};
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/20/)

Comment: Actually I didn't look in other functions properly but logic is same, maybe not the same context.

Comment: Can you be more specific about functions you are taking about ?

Comment: I think you want [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/22/). Check the `App.prototype.end` last line in `else`.

Comment: Glad to know that, then how much you are going to transfer in to my account, lol! :p

Comment: Did you try to get Google Adsense for your website `heera.it`  ?

Answer (score 0):

In jquery, it can be done easily by cancel default action. Here's the sample.

```
$("#btn_start").click(function(event){      
    if(not_active_flag){
        // Prevent anchor to active
        return false;
    }else{
        // Anchor active as usual
        return true;
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the link will ultimately call `this.buttonHandler`, which has the following code:

```
App.prototype.buttonHandler = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent anchor default action
    this.toggle(); // toggle play/pause
};
```

Because `buttonHandler` is attached before `playGetReady` is executed, it is not possible to let `playGetReady` attach a click handler to that anchor element that uses [`.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopImmediatePropagation) to prevent the other click handler from executing.

In this case @gp.'s solution in the comments is most likely the best solution. In your case you might even be able to use a local variable in your app. If you use a global variable, reference it with `window.yourglobalvariable`. If you use a local variable, make sure you define it somewhere and reference it with `this.yourvariable`. Change your buttonHandler to:

```
App.prototype.buttonHandler = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent anchor default action
    if( this.soundready )
        this.toggle(); // toggle play/pause
};
```

On the appropiate place make this variable `false` to prevent the 'button' from working. When the button should work, change the variable to `true`. I think that should be just before `done()` in the code you have in your question, but you probably have a better idea in what order the code is executed.