# Check audio in Watir

Tags: ruby, audio, rspec, watir

I'm new in Watir and Ruby, and I've encountered a problem that needs solving.
Is it possible to check if there is any audio after clicking a play button on a track list?

Here's my code:

```
require 'rspec'
describe "CA" do
  include_context "firefox browser"
    it 'TRACK PLAYBACK' do
      browser.goto MyUrl
      browser.link(:href => '/rock').when_present.click
      browser.a(:class => "album-image").fire_event 'mouseover'
      browser.div(:class, "play-button play-stop-button with-art").when_present.click
#     is there any audio output during playback?  
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm curious how the audio is played (e.g. embedded player?).  Can you post the HTML?

Comment: You'll probably end up using javascript to do this...similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437228/html5-check-if-audio-is-playing