# Web: How to check if audio is playing?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

What's the javascript api for checking if an web audio element is currently playing?
Thank you very much

```
audio = new Audio('music.mp3');
audio.play();

if(audio.isplaying){ //check audio is playing
 audio.pause();
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 check if audio is playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437228/html5-check-if-audio-is-playing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Audio` has `paused` propriety in javascript.
So if the audio is not paused, then it's playing.
Example:

```
audio = new Audio('music.mp3');
audio.play();

if(!audio.paused){ //check audio is playing
 audio.pause();
}
```